# How to sort data by using for loop?

Tags: r, sorting, loops

I am wondering that how to use a loop (may be a for loop) to sort data like following.

```
      [,1]
 [1,]  179
 [2,]  160
 [3,]  136
 [4,]  227
 [5,]  217
 [6,]  168
 [7,]  108
 [8,]  124
 [9,]  143
[10,]  140
```

I tried to use a loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(v)) {
for (j in i+1:nrow(v)) {
if (v[i] > v[j]) {
v[i] <- v[j]
}
else {
v[i] <- v[i]
}
}
}
v
```

But finally a error message turned out :/

```
Error in if (chickwts[i, 1] > chickwts[j, 1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I know that this is very simple by using order to do it, but as a beginner of R, I am curious how to do this by loop.  Hope someone can help.  Thank you!

Comment: Check out `sort`, `rank`, `order`. You can see help file from `> help(sort)`

Comment: actually, i am trying to come out the express after the if statement.
`for (i in nrow(v)) {
for (j in i+1:nrow(v)) {
if (v[i, 1] > v[j, 1]) 
{expression}
}
}
`
I've also tried by search keywords like, sort, loop, and order, also checked the help file.  Sorry about that...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588161/sorting-a-vector-in-r-without-using-sort-function

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is don't, because `sort.list` implements a number sorting algorithms more efficiently using internal, well optimised  code.

You need to decide on the sorting method you wish to use. 
See [this wikipedia artile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)  for a good summary.

Each of the sorting algorithms have psuedocode which can be translated to R

Here is an implementation of a *bubbleSort*, implementing the pseudocode from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
   repeat     
     swapped = false
     for i = 1 to length(A) - 1 inclusive do:
       /* if this pair is out of order */
       if A[i-1] > A[i] then
         /* swap them and remember something changed */
         swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
         swapped = true
       end if
     end for
   until not swapped
end procedure
```

In `R` this would look something like

```
set.seed(1)
A <- sample(10)
A

##  [1]  3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1


n <- length(A)

repeat {
    swapped = FALSE
    for (i in 2:length(A)) {
        newA <- A
        if (A[i - 1] > A[i]) {
            newA[i - 1] <- A[i]
            newA[i] <- A[i - 1]
            A <- newA
            swapped <- TRUE
        }
    }
    if (!swapped) {break}
}
# ta da!
A

##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```