# Sorting a vector in R without using sort function

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to write a function to sort a vector, but without using R's inbuilt 'Sort' function.
My Code:

```
sorting <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    for(j in (i+1):length(x)){
      if(x[i] > x[j]){
        x[c(i,j)] = x[c(j,i)]
      }
    }
  }
  x
}
```

I get below output:

```
> x <- c(3,1,4,7,2,9)
> sorting(x)
Error in if (x[i] > x[j]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>
```

I understand that we'll get above error when the 'IF' condition returns 'NA' instead of TRUE/FALSE.

Is there an issue with the statement:

```
for(j in (i+1):length(x)){
```

Python code for same:

```
def sorting(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):    
        for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
            if a[i] > a[j]:
                a[i],a[j] = a[j],a[i]

    return a
```

Output:

```
sorting([3,1,4,7,2,9])
Out[380]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9]
```

In Python, the code works fine.

Could someone let me know the issue with my R code.

Comment: Bubble sort in R

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/06/how-to-write-bubble-sort-in-r/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with that `(i+1)`. When `length(x)` reaches its max value, `j` goes out of range. I added this: `(length(x)-1)`.

```
sorting <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:(length(x)-1)){
    for(j in (i+1):length(x)){
      if(x[i] > x[j]){
        x[c(i,j)] = x[c(j,i)] # +1 for this
      }
    }
  }
  x
}

sorting(c(3,1,4,7,2,9))
[1] 1 2 3 4 7 9
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
Sorting <- function(x){
    xs <- rep(0, length(x))
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
          xs[i] = min(x)
          x <- x[x != min(x)]
          }
    xs
}

Sorting(c(3,1,4,7,2,9))
[1] 1 2 3 4 7 9
```

Sorting is a function with a numeric vector argument `x`. Initially `xs`, the sorted vector of the same length as `x`, is filled with zeroes. The for loop aims at assigning the minimum value of vector `x` to each component of `xs` `(for(i in 1:length(x)){ xs[i] = min(x) )`. We then remove such minimum value from x by `x <- x[x != min(x)] }` to find the next minimum value. Finally, `xs` shows the sorted vector of `x`.